# PHP: Using DateTime->modify Two Times, Same Result

Tags: php, datetime

I want to have two variables. one `-2 seconds` of a time and another `+2 seconds` of the time. This is my code:

```
$myTime = '2015-08-17 08:19:26';
$myTime = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $myTime);

echo '<pre>';

var_dump( $myTime );

$myTime->modify('+2 seconds');
$myTime_p2 = $myTime;
$myTime->modify('-4 seconds');
$myTime_m2 = $myTime;

var_dump( $myTime );
var_dump( $myTime_p2 );
var_dump( $myTime_m2 );

echo '</pre>';
```

The result is not as expected:

```
object(DateTime)#1 (3) {
  ["date"]=>
  string(26) "2015-08-17 08:19:26.000000"
  ["timezone_type"]=>
  int(3)
  ["timezone"]=>
  string(16) "America/New_York"
}
object(DateTime)#1 (3) {
  ["date"]=>
  string(26) "2015-08-17 08:19:24.000000"
  ["timezone_type"]=>
  int(3)
  ["timezone"]=>
  string(16) "America/New_York"
}
object(DateTime)#1 (3) {
  ["date"]=>
  string(26) "2015-08-17 08:19:24.000000"
  ["timezone_type"]=>
  int(3)
  ["timezone"]=>
  string(16) "America/New_York"
}
object(DateTime)#1 (3) {
  ["date"]=>
  string(26) "2015-08-17 08:19:24.000000"
  ["timezone_type"]=>
  int(3)
  ["timezone"]=>
  string(16) "America/New_York"
}
```

As you see the `$myTime_p2` and `$myTime_m2` variables have the same value. So where is the problem?

Comment: You just have an object and 2 links to the same object. You should copy the object to create a new one

Comment: Thanks. Could you please provide me an example? Thank you in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
$myTime->modify('+2 seconds');
$myTime_p2 = clone $myTime;
$myTime->modify('-4 seconds');
$myTime_m2 = clone $myTime;
```

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE
Using `DateTimeImmutable` as per @Im0rtality's comment below:

```
$myTime = '2015-08-17 08:19:26';
$date = DateTimeImmutable::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s',$myTime);

print $date->modify('+2 seconds')->format('Y-m-d H:i:s') . PHP_EOL;
print $date->modify('-2 seconds')->format('Y-m-d H:i:s') . PHP_EOL;

/*
2015-08-17 08:19:28
2015-08-17 08:19:24
*/
```

---

You need to clone the initial object to get the two variations

```
$myTime = '2015-08-17 08:19:26';
$myTime = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $myTime);

echo '<pre>';

var_dump( $myTime );

$myTime_p2 = clone $myTime;
$myTime_p2->modify('+2 seconds');

$myTime_m2 = clone $myTime;
$myTime_m2->modify('-4 seconds');

var_dump( $myTime );
var_dump( $myTime_p2 );
var_dump( $myTime_m2 );

echo '</pre>';

<pre>object(DateTime)#1 (3) {
  ["date"]=>
  string(26) "2015-08-17 08:19:26.000000"
  ["timezone_type"]=>
  int(3)
  ["timezone"]=>
  string(13) "Europe/Berlin"
}
object(DateTime)#1 (3) {
  ["date"]=>
  string(26) "2015-08-17 08:19:26.000000"
  ["timezone_type"]=>
  int(3)
  ["timezone"]=>
  string(13) "Europe/Berlin"
}
object(DateTime)#2 (3) {
  ["date"]=>
  string(26) "2015-08-17 08:19:28.000000"
  ["timezone_type"]=>
  int(3)
  ["timezone"]=>
  string(13) "Europe/Berlin"
}
object(DateTime)#3 (3) {
  ["date"]=>
  string(26) "2015-08-17 08:19:22.000000"
  ["timezone_type"]=>
  int(3)
  ["timezone"]=>
  string(13) "Europe/Berlin"
}
</pre>
```

Comment: Alternatively you can use [\DateTimeImmutable](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetimeimmutable.php) class, which returns modified copy, but original remains unchanged.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Sam has answered and commented sooner. So I've marked him correct. And thanks for the tip @Im0rtality.

Comment: thanks @Im0rtality, I edited my answer to include sample usage of `DateTimeImmutable`

Comment: that's fine @JohnCroneh, just be careful at the order of the cloning and the `->modify` operations as you should clone first and modify the clone.

Comment: @AlexAndrei, Thanks for the tip. I've came up with **Im0rtality** solution (**DateTimeImmutable**).